# My message box in ASP.NET does not work on the server so what is it used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have uploaded an ASP.NET website to a server and the message boxes are throwing exceptions. I only put up the website for testing. There's a lot of mention of the message box not working on the server in forums. My question then is what is the message box used for?

Comment: What exceptions are thrown by message boxes? What message box are you using, javascript alerts ?

Comment: The MessageBox is *not* used in server applications. It's for desktop applications only. If you see it in server-side code it's a sign of *un*familiarity with server-side programming - at least. A `Debug.Assert` is far better, but true logging is the only solution

Comment: ... did you stop to think that perhaps it's used for things other than ASP.NET applications?

Comment: @JLRishe What would those *server-side* things be? Windows services, web applications, web services, AppFabric hosted services have *no* UI so using a MessageBox is pointless. In fact, they don't even have a desktop on which to display the messagebox.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What are you trying to say? That .NET is only used on servers? I'm confused. I never said that message boxes are used on servers.

Comment: @JLRishe The question is about ASP.NET. My comment was about server applications in general, not just ASP.NET.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you're confused. My comment was directed at OP, not at you.

Comment: @Siva. "Runtime Error" "An application error occurred on the server.  ..." I haven't placed try-catch handlers in yet but I just know it's the message box because I put in an error to check it.

Comment: @JLRishe. I think we are always going to fail in making good assessments at some point. It's a big field isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***messagebox in asp.net is for debugging only***

it works while you're running the code from VS, and won't work on IIS 
if you want to display messages , you can display them on label/div/span/.... what ever html tag you want , just add the runat="server" attribute to it and in code behind change the display ,

```
if something = false then 
    mydiv.style.item("display") = "block"
else
    mydiv.style.item("display") = "none"
end if
```

***or you can use server side control with controlID.visible = true/false***

if you really want to display messagebox - then go to javascript alert, and you can use maybe you want to see this [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef(v=vs.110).aspx) or just google it.

Comment: `Debug.Assert` or `Trace.Assert` are for debugging. Messagebox is a sign the developer is unfamiliar with server-side programming.

Comment: @Thair. It'll be worth trying this out I think.

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` and `System.Windows.MessageBox` classes are for displaying message boxes in Windows forms applications and Windows WPF applications, i.e. client applications.

If you try to use those in a web application, it would show the message box on the web server, not on the client computer. As a web application runs in an account without a user interface (no logged in user), there would be nowhere to show the message box.

In a web appication you would use the `window.alert` or `window.confirm` methods in Javascript to show a simple popup message. If you search for [message box web server control](https://www.google.se/search?q=message%20box%20web%20server%20control) you will find several examples of web server controls implementations and alternatives.

Comment: @Guffa.I was hoping that asp.net could function totally on its own, independent of JavaScript or other scripts, including on alert messages. A bit disappointing.

Comment: @matt2605: To have message box functionality without handling it from client code would mean that you had to trigger a postback to open it (or only open it immediately when the page loads), and it would trigger another postback when the user closes it. I can see how the choise came be not to include something like that in the framework, considering also that popups isn't very great for user experience in the first place.

Comment: PostBack doesn't always work in my favour. I'm guessing that MessageBox doesn't trigger PostBack. I've tried it. I can't even get a button.visble=false to work when back clicking to a previous page. I may put up a new post for that.